# Get the name of the state in Deutsch using OpenStreetMap

Tags: angularjs, openstreetmap, angular-leaflet-directive, overpass-api

Currently I am using below url to get details of given address.

[link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?q=Dolivostrasse%2012%2064293%20Darmstadt%20Deutschland&limit=1&format=json&json_callback=_l_geocoder_0)

respective code in controller to generate above url is as below:

```
var query = [address.streetName, address.streetNumber, address.zipCode, address.city, 'Deutschland'].join(' ');

L.Control.Geocoder.jsonp('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/', {
 q: query,
 limit: 1,
 format: 'json'
}, function (data) {
  if (0 < data.length && ('way' === data[0].osm_type || 'house' === data[0].type)) {
    //do something here
  }
}, this, 'json_callback');
```

The above query will return result like below:

> "place"
>   display_name
>   :
>   "12, Dolivostraße, Pallaswiesenviertel, Darmstadt, Regierungsbezirk Darmstadt, ***Hesse,*** 64293, Germany"
>   importance
>   :
>   0.111
>   lat
>   :
>   "49.8766854"
>   licence
>   :
>   "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"
>   lon
>   :
>   "8.6396259"
>   osm_id
>   :
>   "1791379113"
>   osm_type
>   :
>   "node"
>   place_id
>   :
>   "18711662"
>   type
>   :
>   "house"

I want to have ***'Hessen'*** (which is the name used in Germany) rather than ***'Hesse'***. How to achieve this? Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

See the [Nominatim documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). It mentions parameter `accept-language`:

> Preferred language order for showing search results, overrides the
>   value specified in the "Accept-Language" HTTP header.
>   Either uses standard rfc2616 accept-language string or a simple comma
>   separated list of language codes.

It allows you to specify a list of languages according to the Accept-Language request-header described in RFC2616. To prefer German first and English second simply add `&accept-language=de,en` to your URL.